# Replacing strings in lines

Tags: sed

I have lines like this:

```
    400 january    ####
    304 april    ####
    151 may    ####
    126 june    ####
    115 august    ####
     98 december    ####
```

And I want them to look like this:

```
####  january    400 
####  april    304
####  may    151     
####  june    126     
####  august    115   
####  december    98
```

I tried using this command, but no avail.

```
 sed -E 's/(.*)(.*)(.*) /\3 \2 \1/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sed -E 's/^(.*[0-9])(.*[[:alpha:]])(.*)/\3 \2 \1/' file
    ####  january     400
    ####  april     304
    ####  may     151
    ####  june     126
    ####  august     115
    ####  december      98
```

#### How it works

- `^(.*[0-9])` matches from the beginning of the line to the last number of the line.
- `(.*[[:alpha:]])` matches from the after the above to the last alphabetic character on the line.
- `(.*)` matches anything after the last alphabetic character on the line.

#### Discussion

Consider:

```
sed -E 's/(.*)(.*)(.*) /\3 \2 \1/'
```

sed's regexes match leftmost-longest.  That means that the first `(.*)` above matches the entire line.  The remaining groups are empty.  If we modify the command, this becomes clear:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)(.*)(.*) /3=\3 and 2=\2 and 1=\1/' file
3= and 2= and 1=    400 january   ####
3= and 2= and 1=    304 april   ####
3= and 2= and 1=    151 may   ####
3= and 2= and 1=    126 june   ####
3= and 2= and 1=    115 august   ####
3= and 2= and 1=     98 december   ####
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler way to do it:

```
awk '{print $3," "$2,"   "$1}' file
```

It just uses `awk` to print columns 3, 2, and 1 with two spaces between the 3rd and 2nd column and four spaces between the 2nd and 1st column.

Output:

```
####  january    400
####  april    304
####  may    151
####  june    126
####  august    115
####  december    98
```

If you want it to edit the file in place, use this command:

```
awk -i inplace '{print $3," "$2,"   "$1}' file
```